# send variable to another function every 2 sec

Tags: swift, timer

```
var routingmessage = ["TOAST1","TOAST2","TOAST3"]
```

I am trying to find a way to send routingmessage 1 value, then after 2 sec send the next one to popup as toast.

For example I want:

TOAST1 appear at 00:00:00

TOAST2 at 00:00:02

TOAST3 at 00:00:04

I tried this:

```
for var i in (0..<routingmessage.count-1){
    var timerforToast = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(IndoorRouting.popupToast), userInfo: i, repeats: true)
}
```

But the outpust is pop everything (TOAST1,TOAST2,TOAST3) at 00:00:00

```
@objc func popupToast (val :Timer){
    let userInfo = val.userInfo as! Int

    //toast appear
    self.view.makeToast(routingmessage[i], duration: 1.0, point: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "Toast Title", image: UIImage(named: "toast.png")) { didTap in
        if didTap {
            print("completion from tap")
        } else {
            print("completion without tap")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `asyncAfter`?

```
let durationBetweenToasts: Double = 10
for i in (0 ..< routingMessage.count) {
    let deadline: DispatchTime = .now() + (Double(i) * durationBetweenToasts)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
        popupToast()
    }
}
```

Comment: error appear sir . "Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'DispatchTime"